# Using ES Module style dependencies in Electron 27

Tags: electron, dependencies, node-modules, es6-modules, commonjs

I am developing an desktop application with vanilla JavaScript under `Electron`. I had not configured the packaging workflow like `Webpack` for may project.

Now I am intending to use some third party packages, and some of them is given by **ES module**, using the syntax `export xxx`. It leads that I can't import them successfully in my project.

For example, I want to use the `mermaid` package.

Firstly, the standard method is:

```js
import "mermaid"
```

Obviously it will cause an `Uncaught SyntaxError`. As you know, ES module syntax isn't supported in Electron up to now.

So I wrote like this below:

```
require("mermaid")
```

But it was still unavailable. It would cause another `Uncaught Error`:

```
Uncaught Error: require() of ES Module /path/to/app/node_modules/mermaid/dist/mermaid.core.mjs not supported.
Instead change the require of /path/to/app/node_modules/mermaid/dist/mermaid.core.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

I viewed the source in `mermaid.core.mjs` which was I had required, like this:

```js
import "A";
import "B";
// ...
export {
  L as default
};
```

Sure, it seemed that I should use `import()`. Then, I won't even see the application window but receive a message in terminal.

```
[11752:1106/104603.491:ERROR:crashpad_client_win.cc(863)] not connected
```

Therefore, I had no way. When I tried to search for relevant information, I learned the following information:

- I should add an entry to `package.json`: `"type": "module"`
  This is the method to use ES module in classic node.js project. It does not apply to Electron.
- I should migrate the project to TypeScript.
  However, due to some personal considerations, I am unable to adopt this strategy and still using native JavaScript.
- I should use a framework ecosystem tool chain (e.g. `React`).
  Same as the previous one.
- I should use `Webpack` to help me translate the parts related to `ES6+` syntax into `ES5` and `commonJS`.
  It seems to have some feasibility. I lack experience using webpack. I want to know if this will resolve all these problems and handle all dependencies (it seems including JavaScript >= 100M, Oops!) and package them into a file?

Actually, I had met this issue in more than 10 dependencies. It prevents me from using these irreplaceable dependencies. Except `Webpack` (I currently have no experience working with it!) , do I have a more elegant solution?

Thank you very much for your help! :D